# Can't connect solr9 to zookeeper

Tags: gitlab, apache-zookeeper, solr9

I have this test in a gitlab pipeline

```
test:
  stage: test
  image: maven:3-eclipse-temurin-17-focal
  variables:
    ZK_HOST: zoo:2181
  services:
    - name: zookeeper:3.9-jre-17
      alias: zoo
    - name: solr:9
      alias: solr
      command: ["-c"]
  script:
#    - 'while true; do sleep 10000; done'
```

but this gives the error

```
Could not connect to ZooKeeper zoo:2181 within 30000 ms
```

However, if i change to solr8 it works perfectly fine.
I just want to make sure that one can connect to the other.
What gives?
Thanks in advance!

I tried using solr8 and it worked fine. With solr9 nothing works